# Using ffmpeg to combine decimal format named files into an mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to use ffmpeg to combine png files with this decimal format naming into an mp4, where the file order matters.

```
M_2.50.png
M_3.01.png
M_4.12.png
M_5.07.png
M_6.00.png
M_7.16.png
M_8.01.png
M_9.21.png
M_10.13.png
M_11.16.png
M_12.03.png
M_13.32.png
M_14.04.png
M_15.62.png
```

If my files were of this integer format:

```
M_1.png
M_2.png
M_3.png
M_4.png
M_5.png
M_6.png
M_7.png
M_8.png
M_9.png
M_10.png
M_11.png
M_12.png
M_13.png
M_14.png
M_15.png
```

I would use this inherited script:

```
#images_to_movie.sh
#!/bin/sh

in_files=$1
out_file=$2

$ffmpeg \
    -r 10 \
    -f image2 \
    -s 1200x1200 \
    -i $in_files \
    -vcodec libx264 \
    -crf 25  \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -y \
    $out_file

./images_to_movie.sh path/M_%d.png path/movie.mp4
```

But this doesn't work with the decimal format naming. I get the error:

```
Could find no file with path/M_%d.png' and index in the range 0-4
path/M_%d.png: No such file or directory
```

I am having trouble making sense of the documentation here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options

I think i can use glob, but I'm not sure how to edit the script, or the call to the script, or how to ensure that my files are merged in order.

Answer (score 2):

## Problems

- You can't use the glob pattern because your file names are not padded with 0, as in `M_02.50.png` instead of `M_2.50.png`. So with glob the first image becomes `M_10.13.png`. You can use `ls -m1 *.png` to list files in the order that glob will list them.
- You can't use the pattern sequence because there is no distinct pattern to the file names.

## Solutions

#### Rename files

The obvious solution is to rename the files.

#### Using `sort`

Use "human" / natural / version sorting with `sort --version-sort` or `sort -V`:

```
cat $(find . -name '*.png' -print | sort -V) | ffmpeg -y -framerate 10 -i - -c:v libx264 -crf 25 -vf scale=1200:-2,format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

#### concat demuxer

An alternative solution is to use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat):

1. Create `input.txt` which contains:

   ```
    file 'M_2.50.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_3.01.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_4.12.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_5.07.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_6.00.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_7.16.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_8.01.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_9.21.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_10.13.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_11.16.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_12.03.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_13.32.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_14.04.png'
    duration 0.1
    file 'M_15.62.png'
    duration 0.1
   ```
2. Run `ffmpeg`:

   ```
    ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 25 -vf scale=1200:-2,format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
   ```

Comment: llogan: i previously tried to store the list of sorted files in my `$in_files` variable using `in_files=ls $1 | sort -V` where `$1` is the passed directory. Can you explain why that didn't work? In the meanwhile,  I'll try your suggested sorting.

Comment: @astromonerd `ffmpeg` can't accept a list of files like that. For images has to be a pipe (as shown in my `sort` example), a glob, a pattern, or individually listed (`-i input0 -i input1 -i input2`). Only the concat demuxer can directly accept a list. See [image demuxer docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1).

Comment: that glob pattern works surprisingly well under linux, thanks!